# "On the ground further ahead" or "Further ahead on the ground"?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, idiomatic-language

> The mafia people throw the dead guy off the rooftop. On the parking lot below, Mia, heading for the building, is busy checking messages on her phone. She doesn't see the body drop/crash down on the ground further ahead.

Two questions:

Is "drop" and "crash" both natural in the context?

What is more natural: "on the ground further ahead" or "further ahead on the ground" or none of them?

Comment: Mia might not see the body **drop** down, but she would certainly see it **crash** to the ground a moment later.,

Comment: Thanks. How do I incorporate "further ahead" into that? Would "crash to the ground further ahead" work or is it nor natural?

Comment: Omit **further** Prefer **crash down in front of (or -ahead of) her.